# Stripes over gradient background

Tags: css

I want stripes over gradient background. See the image below for stripes pattern. My gradient background is as follows :

```
 background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(209, 33%, 82%, 1), rgb(240,240,240), hsla(37, 33%, 85%, 1));
```

[image: Stripes]

If you observe bottom part of the image, you would find no Stripes and more gradiant. Stripes should be in only above part of the background.

Answer (score 1):

Set the gradient on the div

Set the stripes on a pseudo

set a mask on this pseudo, going from opaque to transparent

```css
.test {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, hsla(209, 33%, 82%, 1), rgb(240,240,240), hsla(37, 33%, 85%, 1));
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0) 10%, transparent 80%);
            mask-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0) 10%, transparent 80%);
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0px, white 10px, lightblue 10px, lightblue 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the color combination, this is what I could achieve, I guess this may help you to get started:

> You have to change the angle to 45deg.

I hope this helps you:

```css
.stripe {
  width: 800px;
  height: 900px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #dadee0 20px, rgba(125, 168, 196, 0.5)), repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(209, 33%, 82%, 1), rgb(240, 240, 240) 100px, hsla(37, 33%, 85%, 1) 50px);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="stripe"></h2>
```

```css
.stripe {
  width: 500px;
  height: 700px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(45deg, hsla(209, 33%, 82%, 1), rgb(240, 240, 240) 100px, hsla(37, 33%, 85%, 1) 100px);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="stripe"></h2>
```

Or

something like this:

```css
.stripe {
  width: 50%;
  height: 700px;
  margin: 50 auto;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient( 45deg, #83ABC6 0px, #83ABC6 50px, #9BBBCF 50px, #9BBBCF 100px);
}
```

```html
<h2 class="stripe"></h2>
```

Comment: Thank you! If you observe bottom of the image (shown in post), you would find a very light Stripes and more gradiant

Comment: @john you can check my first snippet, I hope that is what you need, if it works let me know I will take out other 2 snippets.

Answer (score -1):

enjoy

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 50px,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 50px,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 100px
    ),
    linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      #c8d5e2,
      #7da9c4
    );
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    content
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

now try this code [EDIT]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      #dadee0,
      rgba(126, 169, 196, 0.5)
    ), repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 50px,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 50px,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 100px
    );
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    content
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

for the latest image [EDIT]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      0deg,
      #dadee0 200px,
      rgba(126, 169, 196, 0.5)
    ), repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      transparent,
      transparent 10px,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 10px,
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 20px
    );
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But it's not close to the desired output (shown in image)

Comment: just play with the colors. its adjactly what you want

Comment: Okay. If you observe bottom part of the image, you would find no Stripes and more gradiant.

Comment: Thanks. I also edited the image for better reference